# Filming a football game from inside the goal. Which camera is best?

Tags: video

So the problem is simple, I'd like a video camera to just leave on record and i can just leave it in the goal mouth, or more preferably at the top of the goal.

I record all my games and then edit them, but having this angle would give a brilliantly close insight into things which we just don't get to see normally.

So any ideas?

Comment: uh, American football or soccer?

Comment: soccer :) my mistake. Also i looked for this site but couldn't find it at the bottom with the list, but i guess its beta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many variables here, depending on cost, what type of shot you want etc., but I would suggest you look at something like the [GoPro HD Hero 2](http://gopro.com/products/?gclid=CPCwmLPM5K4CFUEMfAodMUkxZw) because it is:

- relatively cheap
- takes HD video
- has a range of wide to standard angle FOV
- is waterproof
- has useful mounting brackets
- and is incredibly robust

Comment: humm thanks for the suggestion :) i fear though it might be a little big for the top of the goal. But at the same time this could be perfect for the bottom of the goal.

Comment: They are pretty small. They are designed to attach to a helmet, or bike handlebars, or a surfboard etc

Answer (score 0):

I'll second the vote for the GoPro. I've worked on a number of reality shows that use these cameras for close up work in hazardous situations (like right next to the watermelon that's getting blasted with a shotgun...) because it's HD, it's compact and hide-able, and for the price, more 'expendable' than an XDCAM.

As for the top of the goal...the "naked" version is about the same size as a pack of cigarettes. A consideration might be one at each upper corner, trained on the center...two perspectives. Not sure if your budget allows. But, based on the goals I've seen, I think it'd be just fine on the upper crosspiece, small enough so that it's not distracting. I'd safety chain it so it doesn't bean the keeper if a ball hits it square on and knocks it off the goal. :)

I've had VERY good luck with these in terms of image quality, and the wide angle coverage is really spectacular. I prefer wide, though, YMMV.

Battery life...that's another issue you may have. I know that there's a battery pack that slaps onto the back, making it a bit thicker--maybe the thickness of TWO packs of cigarettes? I'd highly recommend that so you can ensure a full 90 min+ of coverage without having to worry.

Comment: heh i can't even vote up yet ;) A battery pack is a very good idea indeed. Budget is what i want to it to be really :) I will try the one i have bought and if its exciting then 2 is a defo. Maybe 4 is overkill. We shall see, but having both goals is something for me to think about. Means sundays will be interesting from now on